# Getting ORA-01830 while loading a csv file

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a two column table:

```
ID number (automatic sequence number)
Table_Date date
```

When using this code to load a CSV file on the front-end I'm getting ORA-01830.
This is my code:

```
insert into my_table
(
date_entry
)
 
select 
to_date(col001, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
from apex_application_temp_files f, 
       table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                  p_content                     => f.blob_content,
                  p_add_headers_row             => 'Y',
                  p_skip_rows                   => 1,
                  p_csv_col_delimiter           => ';',
                  p_store_profile_to_collection => 'FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION',
                  p_file_name                   => f.filename ) ) p
 where f.name = :P5_LOAD_FILE;
```

Format on the CSV file matches my 'to_date' function (MM/DD/YYYY).
Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found the issue:
p_csv_col_delimiter           => ';'

being a CSV I was to use commas instead of semicolon.

Thanks